# Cloud-flare Cache Purge does not work when having specific rule

Tags: caching, browser-cache, cloudflare, purge

Cache purge does not work (**even not purge everything**) if I add a rule like following (Image#1) => set both **Browser Cache TTL and Edge Cache TTL to 4 hours**

By does not work I mean, url is still cached, shown in image three, the url first time (before opening after the rules (mentioned above) added, url takes above 500ms every time, but after caching it takes 2ms, even after pruge (shown in image2), also tried purge everything.

### **Image#1**

[image: Cache Rule]

---

### **Image#2**

[image: Cache Purge]

---

### **Image#3**

[image: After Cache Purge]

---

### So I am stuck with purge does not work at all after having such a rule (Image#1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe the issue here is that Cloudflare doesn't support Wildcard purge, on lower plan levels. You must enter the exact URL(s) you want to purge (one-by-one) or clear all cache completely for entire site.